# Windows Vista Phantom User

Tags: windows-vista

Recently, my friend's computer had a strange phenomenon. She has only one user for the whole system, named `User`. Recently, she saw different content on her desktop, and the different style of start menu (normally, she uses classic style, but she saw a Vista style).

When I checked out her computer, I saw a TEMP folder located right under `C:/Users`
and the desktop content inside `C:/Users/TEMP/Desktop` was exactly like what had been on the desktop at that time (meanwhile she was logged in using `User` account)

In another folder, `C:/Users/User/Desktop`, were her files
She managed to move file from her old Desktop to the current Desktop.

Later, after a reboot, the desktop was restored to the original, and all files she moved to the new Desktop is long gone. I checked out her computer again: the C:/Users/TEMP folder no longer existed.

When I tried Windows Vista Search, I can still see the the name of files of `C:/Users/TEMP/Desktop` in the index, but these files are inaccessible since they are deleted.

What kind of funny stuff is that? How should people avoid such a thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your friend was looged into a [temporary profile](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947242) which explains the path `\Users\TEMP`.

Something could have happened that corrupted her profile files/settings. Since she is now able to log back into her actual profile, I guess the system fixed the problem itself.

Search for 'Vista Temporary Profile" and see if any of the search results described similar symptoms, e.g. displaying error messages.